# The link to the bot in viber is cut out in mail

Tags: html, wordpress, email, viber

I have an email template in HTML format. The email contains messenger icons and links to bots.

When I open the email template in a browser like a regular webpage, the links work fine. However, when I open the same email in Gmail or the mobile app, the link to the Telegram bot works, but the link to the Viber bot gets removed.

The link to the Viber bot looks like this: `viber://pa?chatURI=*****`. How should I correctly write the link? Currently, I'm using the standard format: `<a href="viber://pa?chatURI=*****"><img src="*********"></a>`.